# JUnit testing a method with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have made a game where a user and an AI takes turns "rolling" a dice. The game automatically takes the AI's turn and returns to the user's turn. I used JOptionPane.showMessageDialog to popup a dialog box notifying the user that it is their turn. So all this is working properly but when I execute a JUnit test class to test the hold() method the popup comes up. Is there a way to suppress the popup or automatically close the window in a JUnit Test class?

```
    public void hold() {

    this.swapWhoseTurn();           
    this.setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers();

    if (this.getCurrentPlayer().getIsMyTurn() == this.getComputerPlayer().getIsMyTurn()) {
        this.theComputer.takeTurn();
        this.hold();
        HumanPlayerPanel.turnAlert();
    }
```

The turnAlert is a static method in another class called HumanPlayerPanel. Here is the code.

```
    public static void turnAlert() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is your turn");
    }
```

I saw that I can call doClick method on the OK_Option button but I'm not too sure how to find that button. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with JUnit, but from understanding, it's not very well suited to UI testing.  You need to use a framework which can interact with the UI within the confines of it's thread (Event Dispatching Thread) and which can interact with the various components (like the button for example).

Comment: I found this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597425/how-do-simulate-a-button-click-in-a-swing-pop-up-dialog but I don't understand how to override the method calling the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog window in the JUnit test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor if statement as follows:

```
 if (this.getCurrentPlayer().getIsMyTurn() == this.getComputerPlayer().getIsMyTurn()) {
        this.theComputer.takeTurn();
        this.hold();
        HumanPlayerPanel.turnAlert();
    }
```

to look like this:

```
...
 if (this.getCurrentPlayer().getIsMyTurn() == this.getComputerPlayer().getIsMyTurn()) {
        this.theComputer.takeTurn();
        this.hold();
        alertHumanPlayer();
    }
...

protected void alertHumanPlayer(){
    HumanPlayerPanel.turnAlert();
}
```

Let's assume above class is called Game. In your test code, extend Game class as follows:

```
...
public class GameWithNoHumanAlert extends Game{
    @Override
    protected void alertHumanPlayer(){
        // Do not show alert
        // HumanPlayerPanel.turnAlert();
    }
}

@Test
public void uiTest(){
    GameWithNoHumanAlert game = new GameWithNoHumanAlert();

    ...
    // Do your testing normally now.  

}
```

**__UPDATE__**

Another, and IMHO a better, idea would be to use [mock testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). I have personally tried several of them and I an suggest you to take a look at [Jmockit](http://jmockit.org/). It is almost trivial to deal with this kind of troubles with it so that you can focus on what you want to / need to test.

Cheers.

Comment: Wow this is great! I actually just decided to move the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog in a view class and triggered it there. Since I don't need to run any JUnit testing on GUI classes I didn't have to deal with the popup. I appreciate your effort though! This forum never ceases to amaze me. Thank you!